# Delay Trigger Execution

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Let me explain the scenario first before asking the question.

I have a database with a set of tables. One table, say Table A, contains username details, and other table, say Table B, contains user activity log. I want to delete the specific user log from Table B when that specific user entry is deleted from Table A. I can do this with a trigger, but there is a requirement that entries from Table B should be deleted after sometime (say after 5 minutes), not immediately.

Is it possible to delay trigger execution for 5 minutes? What could be the possible design for trigger. Whether deferred trigger will be helpful in this scenario.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, deferred trigger execution will not help. It only defers triggers until the end of the transaction.

PostgreSQL doesn't have a built-in task/job scheduler, either, so you'll need to do this in your app.

In the trigger, insert a row into a table that keeps track of which entries should be deleted and when. Scan that table every few minutes and, in a single transaction, records that're past their expiry time and their corresponding entry in the delete queue table.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have created a job scheduler for this problem. Whenever the app deletes the record from table A, then at same time it schedules a new job using scheduler. The newly created job deletes the records for specific user from Table B after required time.